# Upper_bound and lower_bound doesn't compile

Tags: c++, sorting, compiler-errors, lower-bound, upperbound

I would like to getting the first position and last position of the searched name.

I can't compile this code, although I've seen similar instructions being executed. Gives an error in lower_bound and upper_bound.

Compiled in C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Client
{
public:
    int id;
    string name;
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Client>::iterator low;
    vector<Client>::iterator up;
    string s_name;

    Client c1;
    c1.id = 1;
    c1.name = "jhon";
    c1.number = 123;

    Client c2;
    c2.id = 2;
    c2.name = "Mart";
    c2.number = 987;

    Client c3;
    c3.id = 3;
    c3.name = "Jhon";
    c3.number = 256;

    Client c4;
    c4.id = 4;
    c4.name = "Anna";
    c4.number = 851;

    vector<Client> vCli{c1, c2, c3, c4};

    sort(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), [](Client a, Client b) { return a.name < b.name; });

    s_name = "Jhon";

    low = lower_bound(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_name, [](Client a, Client b) { return a.name < b.name; });
    up = upper_bound(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_name, [](Client a, Client b) { return a.name < b.name; });

    cout << (low - vCli.begin()) << endl;
    cout << (up - vCli.begin()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.1.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h|144|
error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(Client, Client)>) (Client&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'|
```

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You could use the second edit. Where I actually removed them.

Comment: @churill thx, missed that

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 
Excuse me. I am confused by an edit of the posts here.

Comment: what edit do you mean? I formatted the error message, churill removed the `>`....

Comment: ¨@formerlyknownas_463035818 
Ok, thanks for the formatting. The '<' was added when the code block was placed

Answer (score 2):

The third argument to `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` has to be a `Client` object or something that can be converted to a `Client`. If you add a constructor in `Client` that allows you to construct a `Client` from a `std::string` implicitly, your code would work. Here's a quick fix that does not require any other changes to your code.

```
Client s;
s.name =  "Jhon";

low = lower_bound (vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s, [](Client a, Client b) { return a.name <  b.name; });
up  = upper_bound (vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s, [](Client a, Client b) { return a.name <  b.name; });
```

Comment: @R Sahu Perfect my friend. Thank you very much. I need to solve another problem, if you can help me would be grateful. If I had compound names ("Jhon Mutts", "Jhon Hill"), how would I do the research? As top and bottom, search only the first name.

Comment: @DiegoHilário, you'll have to separate name into first name and last name. Then you can search for items using first name or last name. If you want to search for both, lookup [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

Comment: more precisely it has to be of a type that can be converted to the type of the second parameter of the comparator, eg if `Client` had a constructor taking a string it would have worked as well

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, indeed.

Comment: @R Sahu I gathered the names and searched, but the functions do not return the correct positions. Splitting names is relatively easy, but I don't know how to search separately.

Comment: @DiegoHilário, I suggest you create another post, with a suitable [mcve].

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 
could you exemplify?

Comment: @RSahu 
 I'll do it. Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoHilário exemplify what? Did you try to supply a constructor taking a string ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class Client
{ 
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int number; 
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Client> vCli =
    {
        { 1, "Jhon", 123 },
        { 2, "Mart", 987 },
        { 3, "Jhon", 256 },
        { 4, "Anna", 851 },
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( vCli ), std::end( vCli ),
               []( const Client &c1, const Client &c2 )
               {
                    return c1.name < c2.name; 
               } );

    std::string s_name = "Jhon";

    auto low = std::lower_bound( std::begin( vCli ), std::end( vCli ), s_name,
                                []( const Client &c, const std::string &s )
                                {
                                    return c.name < s;
                                } );

    auto up = std::upper_bound( std::begin( vCli ), std::end( vCli ), s_name,
                                []( const std::string &s, const Client &c )
                                {
                                    return s < c.name;
                                } );

    for ( auto first = low; first != up; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << first->id << ", "  
                  << first->name << ", "
                  << first->number << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1, Jhon, 123
3, Jhon, 256
```

Instead of separate calls of `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` you could use one call of `std::equal_range`. In this case you should define a function object as shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class Client
{ 
public:
    int id;
    std::string name;
    int number; 
};

struct Compare_by_name
{
    bool operator ()( const Client &c, const std::string &s ) const
    {
        return c.name < s;
    }

    bool operator ()( const std::string &s, const Client &c ) const
    {
        return s < c.name;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Client> vCli =
    {
        { 1, "Jhon", 123 },
        { 2, "Mart", 987 },
        { 3, "Jhon", 256 },
        { 4, "Anna", 851 },
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( vCli ), std::end( vCli ),
               []( const Client &c1, const Client &c2 )
               {
                    return c1.name < c2.name; 
               } );

    std::string s_name = "Jhon";

    auto low_up = std::equal_range( std::begin( vCli ), std::end( vCli ), s_name,
                                    Compare_by_name() );   


    for ( auto first = low_up.first; first != low_up.second; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << first->id << ", "  
                  << first->name << ", "
                  << first->number << '\n';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

This function object you can use also with `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` instead of their lambda expressions.

Comment: Thank you so much friend. It helped me a lot. I will study more about this function std :: equal_range

Answer (score 1):

As you are searching for a `std::string` one argument in your comparator needs to be a `std::string` not a `Client`:

```
low = lower_bound(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_name, [](const Client& a, const std::string& b) { return a.name < b; });
up = upper_bound(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), s_name, [](const std::string& a, const Client& b) { return a < b.name; });
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend. Your explanation clarified my studies.